# how to read json object inside json array using jersy in java?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

```
Here is my JSON array.
{ "pidValues":
[{"PID":"12344","associatedSubFeatureID":"1","dashboardName":"CWC"},
{"PID":"12345","associatedSubFeatureID":"1","dashboardName":"WSM"}] 
}
```

I need to retrieve the value of PID in String array.
I am using jersey framework.

Comment: does the [Oracle Java API for JSON processing link help](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html)\

Comment: No it didn't help in my case. i tried the solution but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject(your_JSON_Repsonse);
JSONArray data_pidValues=data.getJSONArray(pidValues);
for(int i=0;i<=data_pidValues.length();i++)
{
 PID=data_pidValues.getString("PID");
associatedSubFeatureID=data_pidValues.getString("associatedSubFeatureID");
dashboardName=data_pidValues.getString("dashboardName");
}
```

Comment: pidValuse will be like "pidValues" ?  and i am expecting value as String from GUI so in your_JSON_Repsonse i wrote String response but still code isn't working.

Comment: As i am using jersey the method you suggested doesn't work. I used below code to parse.

Comment: Go through this Link:-    https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/rest/jersey/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/

Answer (score 0):

```
    As I am using jersey the method you suggested above doesn't work. I used below code to parse.
@Path("/any")
@Consumes("application/json")    
public String getAllData(JSONArray pidValues)
    {
    String [] accessiblepid = new String[pidValues.size()];
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> mapList = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

            String subProgId="";
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
            JSONArray jsonArrayPid = new JSONArray();

            for (int i=0; i<pidValues.size();i++)
                {

                System.out.println(pidValues.get(i));
                mapList =(LinkedHashMap<String, String>) pidValues.get(i);
                System.out.println(mapList.get("PID"));
                accessiblepid[i] = mapList.get("PID").toString();
                jsonArray.add(mapList.get("dashboardName").toString());
                jsonArrayPid.add(mapList.get("PID").toString());
                subProgId=mapList.get("associatedSubFeatureID");
                }
        return "";
    }
```